# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Route' not found

Tags: php, laravel

When I upload the files I faced following problem

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Route' not found in C:\inetpub\vhosts\classymoodkw.com\httpdocs\routes\admin.php:14 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\inetpub\vhosts\classymoodkw.com\httpdocs\routes\admin.php on line 14

How to solve it please

Comment: Please read the guide on how to ask a good question on this site. Starting from the fact that your question make no sense at all to someone other than you who is familiar with your system. And I am fairly confident it has nothing to do with SQL Server hence removing the tag.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Route]
[From the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#basic-routing), it's clear that it requires you to import the Route facade. Did you forget to use the import statement?

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply I added the statement  still same error